# Is there a way to force an app to stay in the background?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I have an annoying app that pops into the foreground every once in a while. I want to make it stay in the background unless I switch to it.

EDIT: (More information requested)

The app is the iPhone Simulator and it annoyingly pops up every time I run tests in Xcode. I would love for it to stay in the background.

If this isn't possible, is it possible to write a script to make the iPhone Simulator move to the background?

Comment: more specific information please?

Comment: like do you want to know what app it is? i'm looking for a generic solution, but if thats not possible i would appreciate any answer.

Comment: Chances are there's no generic solution. If you have a specific problem you'd like to have solved, please consider adding more details.

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions about the same issue. You can place a bounty on the question if you want to draw attention. Because I'm generous today I offered a bounty on your post :)

Comment: Wow, that is really nice of you. I didn't mean for it to turn into the same question (thats why I was looking for a generic answer) but thank you.